# Как можно получить список ПК в домене?

Tags: c#

Как можно получить список ПК в домене(ip, имена ПК), находясь вне домена и имея доменную учётку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даный код достает хостнеймы

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

public void PrintComputersInDomain (string domainName)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://" + domainName);
    de.Children.SchemaFilter.Add ("computer");
    foreach (DirectoryEntry c in de.Children)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (c.Name);
    }
}
```

взято с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464983/get-list-of-computers-in-a-domain-using-net

Если код не устроит, возьми отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694513/how-to-list-users-in-all-domains-running-code-from-a-non-domain-computer

Следующий код достает айпишник по хостнейму:

```
IPHostEntry hostEntry;

hostEntry= Dns.GetHostEntry(host);

if (hostEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
{
      var ip = hostEntry.AddressList[0];
      //you might get more than one ip for a hostname since 
      //DNS supports more than one record
}
```

взято с:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248971/resolve-hostname-to-ip

Comment: По-хорошему, надо бы обращаться к DNS домена, а не к тому который прописан в системе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov А можно поподробнее?

Comment: @DenArt знал бы - написал бы. Но код из ответа работает только если DNS-зона домена - публичная.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я дал внутри ответа еще одну линку, с которой не вставлял код в ответ... Возможно она поможет. :) Если же нет -- так же ничего детальнее не подскажу.